# ROS Packages Not Found in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ros

I wanted to give ROS a try on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine and I installed the ROS packages as per instructions given in the ROS website, but after successful installation, roscd fails with command not found:

```
joesan@joesan-InfinityBook-S-14-v5:/opt/ros/noetic$ roscd
bash: roscd: command not found
joesan@joesan-InfinityBook-S-14-v5:/opt/ros/noetic$
```

Here is the content inside the noetic folder:

```
joesan@joesan-InfinityBook-S-14-v5:~$ cd /opt/ros/noetic/
drwxr-xr-x joesan joesan   4 KB Sat Aug 29 08:46:37 2020  .
drwxr-xr-x joesan joesan   4 KB Fri Aug 28 21:18:54 2020  ..
.rw-r--r-- joesan joesan   0 B  Fri Jul 24 18:47:51 2020  .catkin
.rw-r--r-- joesan joesan  55 B  Fri Jul 24 18:47:51 2020  .rosinstall
.rwxr-xr-x joesan joesan  13 KB Fri Jul 24 18:47:51 2020  _setup_util.py
drwxr-xr-x joesan joesan   4 KB Fri Aug 28 21:19:38 2020  bin
.rwxr-xr-x joesan joesan 506 B  Fri Jul 24 18:47:51 2020  env.sh
drwxr-xr-x joesan joesan   4 KB Fri Aug 28 21:18:54 2020  etc
drwxr-xr-x joesan joesan   4 KB Fri Aug 28 21:19:39 2020  include
drwxr-xr-x joesan joesan  12 KB Fri Aug 28 21:19:39 2020  lib
.rw-r--r-- joesan joesan 283 B  Fri Jul 24 18:47:51 2020  local_setup.bash
.rw-r--r-- joesan joesan 346 B  Fri Jul 24 18:47:51 2020  local_setup.sh
.rw-r--r-- joesan joesan 293 B  Fri Jul 24 18:47:51 2020  local_setup.zsh
.rw-r--r-- joesan joesan 260 B  Fri Jul 24 18:47:51 2020  setup.bash
.rw-r--r-- joesan joesan 2.7 KB Fri Jul 24 18:47:51 2020  setup.sh
.rw-r--r-- joesan joesan 270 B  Fri Jul 24 18:47:51 2020  setup.zsh
drwxr-xr-x joesan joesan  12 KB Fri Aug 28 21:19:40 2020  share
joesan@joesan-InfinityBook-S-14-v5:/opt/ros/noetic$
```

As you can see I have this line in my .bashrc as well:

```
# Source the ROS setup profile
source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash
```

Any ideas why I could not get roscd command working? I installed the full version:

```
sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop-full
```

Is there anything that I'm missing?

Comment: I suspect that something with that sourcing isn't working. To debug this, can you run `declare` in your shell to see whether `roscd` is defined (it's a function, not a script). Also try manually sourcing `/opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash` once more in a shell and see whether that changes things.

Comment: Manually sourcing got me this error: bash: cd: too many arguments

Comment: Can you elaborate? Did you get that error when running `source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash`, or after you ran that and trying `roscd` again?

Comment: are you sure you are using bash as your shell?

Comment: Yes, I got that error after sourcing it. Here is a post that I created this morning regarding it https://askubuntu.com/questions/1271029/ubuntu-20-04-cd-bash-too-many-arguments-error

Comment: echo $0 gives me /bin/bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally I was able to get this resolved! I have a .bash_profile where I have all my user specific commands and shortcuts. In this file I also source additional setup files. So what I did now was to remove the source command for ROS from the .bashrc and put this in the .bash_profile file and source the whole .bash_profile file from within .bashrc like this:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_profile ]; then
    . ~/.bash_profile
fi
```

In the .bash_profile, I have the source command like this:

```
# Source the ROS setup profile
source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash
```

This help me fix the error!

Comment: Glad you fixed it. But this doesn't really explain why it wasn't working in first place. This doesn't look like a good solution to me, either, because rather than figuring out why the standard way doesn't work for you, you made your setup even less standard now, quite possibly causing yourself other trouble down the road.

Comment: How do you think it is even less standard? I'm just sourcing this from the .bash_profile instead of putting this in the .bashrc.

Comment: I think may be it has got to do with the lsd installation. I remember facing an issue with the /opt folder https://github.com/Peltoche/lsd/issues/392